# Simplify $G(t) = \sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} (\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}-1) \cos(\frac{nt\pi}{3}) $

Tags: summation, fourier-series

Simplify $G(t) = \sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty} (\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}-1) \cos(\frac{n\pi t}{3}) $

I am unsure how to simplify this in the best form, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: is  the first $\cos$ argument $\frac{n \pi}{2}$ or $\frac{n \pi t}{2}$ ?

Comment: it is $\frac{n\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ (\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}-1) \cos(\frac{nt\pi}{3}) = \\ \frac{1}{2} \cos\left( n \left(\frac{\pi t}{3} - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2} \cos\left( n \left(\frac{\pi t}{3} + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right) -\cos \left( \frac{n \pi t}{3} \right) $$

So all terms are cosines.

Comment: It uses $\cos(a) \cos(b) \equiv \frac{1}{2} \cos(a-b) + \frac{1}{2} \cos(a+b)$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate representation using the fact that

\begin{equation}
\cos\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right)-1=\begin{cases}
-1&\text{ for }n=4k-3,\,n=4k-1\\
-2&\text{ for }n=4k-2\\
\phantom{-}0&\text{ for }n=4k\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{eqnarray*}
G(t)&=&-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\cos\left(\frac{4k-3}{3}\pi t\right)
+2\cos\left(\frac{4k-2}{3}\pi t\right)
+\left.\cos\left(\frac{4k-1}{3}\pi t\right)\right]\right.
\end{eqnarray*}